# How to order by desc of event date/time

Tags: sql, sybase

How can I order by `desc` of the event timestamp which is in the form `"29 Jan 2016 2:30[AM|PM]"` ? that is, if I have `29 Jan 2016 2:30AM` and `29 Jan 2016 4:30PM`, then the PM should come first. Right now, the result is showing AM comes first.

Comment: What datatype is it stored in?

Comment: it's datetime datatype

Comment: Can you show examples of this happening - post your query and your results. From your description, it should order ascending as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
order by CONVERT(datetime,ColumnName) Desc
```

Comment: If the column is DATETIME, there's no need to convert.

Comment: @AbeCrabtree Yes If datetime datatype of column no need convert.